# Terminal Command to take timelapse, How to stop after X time?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I have a client that gave me all his photos in a slideshow as a DVD, so I want to take a screenshot every X seconds, I have that command here.

```
i=1;while [ 1 ];do screencapture -t jpg -x ~/Desktop/screencapture/$i.jpg; let i++;sleep 4; done
```

Now I just need to know what to tack onto this command to stop terminate itself after X seconds/mins/hours. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, you can use the special variable `SECONDS` that counts up from whatever you assign to it:

```
SECONDS=0;
i=1; 
while (( SECONDS < 3600 ));
do 
  screencapture -t jpg -x ~/Desktop/screencapture/$i.jpg;
  let i++;
  sleep 4; 
done
```